# SQL CONVERT from varbinary to varchar

Tags: c#, sql, varchar, varbinary

I'm using a C# application and it looks like its ready to insert the image to my database, but my stored procedure spits out an implicit conversion error. I read the image into a byte array and pass the byte array to my stored procedure. It expects a `varbinary` parameter, hence the error. So I alter my stored procedure to be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE insertPlayerImage 
      @playerID varchar(9), 
      @profileImage varchar(max), 
      @pending char(1)
AS
    CONVERT(varbinary(max), @profileImage)

INSERT INTO PlayerImage(playerID, profileImage, pending)
VALUES(@playerID, @profileImage, @pending)
GO
```

which tells me it expects a `varchar` (my byte array) and convert the array to a `varbinary` file. Well my stored procedure doesn't like the the convert line i have.  but if I simply do

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE());
```

it works. All google searches point back to converting the date, almost as if its the only thing you can use a convert on.

Comment: If you need to **store** a `varbinary(max)` value - **why on earth** are you not using a `varbinary(max)` as the **parameter type** in the first place?!?!?

Comment: in my database, the datatype is a varbinary max.  im trying to allow a user to upload a picture and save it.  all the examples of that, read the picture to a byte array.  but when i tried to pass my byte array to my stored proc, it gave me the conversion error.  so i changed the @profileImage to be a varchar, and in my stored proc i was going to convert it from the byte array (varchar) to the varbinary.

Comment: Yes - so if it's `varbinary(max)` in the database, then the stored procedure parameter should **also** be `varbinary(max)`: ` @profileImage varbinary(max)` - then you **don't need** any conversions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SQL Server? If so, see this page for the SQL data type to CLR data type mappings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

SQL Server `char`, `varchar`, `nchar` and `nvarchar` all map to/from a C# `string` (though a `char[]` will work as well).

SQL Server `binary and`varbinary`map to/from a C#`byte[]`.

What's the actual problem you're having?

Further, if you're passing binary data as a varchar to SQL Server, I would expect it to get munged in the tranformation between UTF-16 (CLR internal string encoding) to whatever code page SQL Server is using.

Another thing to note: your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE insertPlayerImage 
  @playerID varchar(9), 
  @profileImage varchar(max), 
  @pending char(1)
AS

  CONVERT(varbinary(max), @profileImage)

  INSERT INTO PlayerImage
  ( playerID , profileImage , pending )
  VALUES
  ( @playerID , @profileImage , @pending )

GO
```

isn't legal SQL. `Convert()` is a function, not a SQL statement. It doesn't even compile. If you are trying to convert your `varchar` parameter `@profileImage` to `varbinary`, you're going to have to do something along the lines of

```
 declare @image varbinary(max)
 set @image = convert(varbinary(max),@profileImage)
```

If you're stored procedure has the signature

```
create procedure dbo.insertPlayerImage

  @playerId     varchar(9) ,
  @profileImage varbinary(max) ,
  @pending      char(1)

as
...
```

Then this code will do you:

```
public int insertProfileImage( string playerId , byte[] profileImage , bool pending )
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(playerId) ) throw new ArgumentException("playerId" ) ;
  if ( profileImage == null || profileImage.Length < 1 ) throw new ArgumentException("profileImage") ;

  int rowCount ;

  string connectString = GetConnectString() ;
  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString) )
  using ( SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
    command.CommandText = "dbo.insertPlayerImage" ;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@playerId"     , playerId            ) ;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@profileImage" , profileImage        ) ;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@pending"      , pending ? "Y" : "N" ) ;

    rowCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery() ;

  }

  return rowCount ;
}
```

If however, you're passing a `null` for image data, you'll need to change how the value of the parameter gets set. Something along the lines of:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@profileImage" , profileImage != null ? (object)profileImage : (object)DBNull.Value ) ;
```

Or

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter( "@profileImage" , SqlDbType.VarBinary ) ;
p.Value = DBNull.Value ;
if ( profileImage != null )
{
  p.Value = profileImage ;
}
command.Parameters.Add( p ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use varbinary(max) as the parameter type.  if not, then you are not setting up your db command object or parameters correctly before issuing Execute.

```
 public DataTable ExecuteParameterizedStoredProcedureObjects(string procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable();
            var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, _sqlConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            foreach (var entry in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                _sqlConnection.Open();
                da.Fill(dataTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteQuery Error : QueryString={0} :: Error={1}", procedureName, ex.Message);
                throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                da.Dispose();
                _sqlConnection.Dispose();
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

Call it with something like :

```
 foreach (var record in missingGridEntries)
             {
                 var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                 parameters.Add("@DataID",int.Parse(record.NodeId));
                 var results = _llDb.ExecuteParameterizedStoredProcedureObjects("listFullPath",parameters);

                 foreach(DataRow dataRow in results.Rows)
                 {
                     record.NodePath = dataRow["fullpath"].ToString();
                     record.NodeFilename = dataRow["name"].ToString();
                 }

             }
```

Comment: I will try this, or take what you have and use a variation of it. i use data tables but do not use the c# stored procedure type

Comment: The CommandType.StoredProcedure tells the ODBC driver that you are going to be calling a stored procedure on the server, rather than directly querying a table or view.  You definitely want to use it!

Answer (score 0):

OK - you need this:

Stored procedure to get the parameter as `varbinary(max)` so you can insert it into a `Varbinary(max)` column in the database table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertPlayerImage 
      @playerID varchar(9), 
      @profileImage varbinary(max), 
      @pending char(1)
AS
    CONVERT(varbinary(max), @profileImage)

    INSERT INTO PlayerImage(playerID, profileImage, pending)
    VALUES(@playerID, @profileImage, @pending)
```

C# code to get the contents of a file uploaded in ASP.NET and calling this stored procedure:

```
// set up connection and command
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string-here"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.insertPlayerImage"))
{
    // define parameters
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 9);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@playerImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pending", SqlDbType.Char, 1);

    // set the parameter values
    cmd.Parameters["@playerID"].Value = Session["playerID"].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@playerImage"].Value = uplImage.FileBytes;
    cmd.Parameters["@pending"].Value = "Y";

    // open connection, execute stored procedure, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

There's really absolutely **no need** to ever convert the uploaded file's contents from `byte[]` to anything else (and back!) - just set the value of the `varbinary(max)` parameter and call that stored procedure - that's all you need to do!